# Selenium Grid+TestNG+Maven+pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

Hi I have a number of selenium tests to run on Jenkins, using a pom.xml setup - my issue is once the first test fails - no more tests will be run.

Failed tests:

```
TSLandingPageTest.testInit:73 » NoSuchElement no such element: Unable to locat...
  TSLoginEmployeeTest.testTSLoginBGImage:108 » NoSuchElement no such element: Un...
  TSLoginEmployeeTest.testTSLoginPortlet:121 » NoSuchElement no such element: Un...
  TSLoginEmployeeTest.testTSLoginTopBanner:93 Login Page Title expected:<Login | IBM Talent Management Solutions> but was:<Invalid URL | IBM Talent Management Solutions>

Tests run: 174, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 167
```

How do i get all tests to run, even if some do fail ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

do you mean @before method or first Test?

if your tests are skipped because @Before method is failing but you want to continue the test, you can run using following parameter.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

```
-configfailurepolicy continue
```

if your first test is failing and other are skipped, it could be due to dependency
There are two ways to do this.

1. Remove the dependency
2. Test you want to run even if dependent test fails, mark them as `alwaysRun=True`

Comment: HI No it is @before or the first test

Comment: Above I'm running 174 tests - on the above test run 167 tests were skipped, so really only 7 tests ran. This is due to test 7 failing and then all remaining tests are skipped. I want all tests to run or attempt to run, and have skipped equal zero.